# TabItem + AsyncImage - image is extremly big

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-asyncimage

I'm trying to load image async using AsyncImage - but the results is that the image is very big and covers all the screen.

```
        TabView { 
         CreateView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            }
        
         AccountView()
            .tabItem {
                let imageUrl = LoginManager.shared.profile!.profileImageUrl
                
                ZStack {
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageUrl)) { phase in
                        switch phase {
                        case .empty:
                            ProgressView()
                        case .success(let image):
                            image.resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(maxWidth: 56, maxHeight: 56)
                        case .failure:
                            Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                        @unknown default:
                            // Since the AsyncImagePhase enum isn't frozen,
                            // we need to add this currently unused fallback
                            // to handle any new cases that might be added
                            // in the future:
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: 56, maxHeight: 56)
            }
    }
```

Tried to put .frame bounds in every single place but the image is extremely big!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for assisting!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't a `.tabItem` take a label? I know you can initialize it without the `Label` init, but underneath, I think it is just a label. That may be the root of your issue.

Comment: @Yrb it takes a label and according to docs you can put any View, and it works well with the other tabs that are showing system image, only the one with AsyncImage causes issues.

Comment: That was kind of my point. You need to be focused on how to put a downloaded image into a label. You may need to create a different view that you then put into the `Label`. SF Symbols (system images) are made to go into the labels. I have put in custom SF Symbols into tabs, but never an image.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using ZStack.
Although it's tricky, but working completely.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
        TabView(selection: $myViewModel.tabSelection) {
            View0().tabItem {
                Image("image1")
                Text("image1")
            }.tag(0)
            View1().tabItem {
                Image("image2")
                Text("image2")
            }.tag(1)
            View2().tabItem {
                Text("AsyncImage image3 ")
            }.tag(2)
        }

        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                myViewModel.tabSelection = 2
            }) {
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://sample.com/a.png")){ image in
                    image.resizable()
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　.scaledToFit()
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                                .opacity(myViewModel.tabSelection == 2 ? 0.8 : 0.4)
                } placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 30)
        }
        .offset(x: (geometry.size.width / 3 * 2 + geometry.size.width / 6 - 15), y: -15)
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of a hacky solution of course but I don't think there is another way to achieve this without building a custom TabView from scratch. Worked for me, thanks for sharing.